# Why is my Groovy object initializer failing to set the property?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have a Groovy class like so:

```
class Person {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    Status status = StatusEnum.ACTIVE
}
```

And I'm creating an instance of it with an object initializer:

```
def person = new Person(
    firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Yelo", status: StatusEnum.INACTIVE)
```

However, this doesn't modify the person's status and it remains as `ACTIVE`. I have to explicitly declare it:

```
person.status = StatusEnum.INACTIVE
```

Which properly sets the status. Does anyone know why I have to explicitly set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's having something to do with the type of the field being `Status` rather than `StatusEnum`?

Declaring it like this worked as you're suggesting it should groovy console:

```
enum StatusEnum {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE
}

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    StatusEnum status = StatusEnum.ACTIVE
}

def person = new Person(firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Yelo", status: StatusEnum.INACTIVE)

assert StatusEnum.INACTIVE == person.status
```